# Run iTunes on Linux

Tags: wine, elementary-os, itunes

I'm running elementary OS (Luna). It mostly works fine, but I really need iTunes, which seems to only run on Windows and OSX. Is there any way to get iTunes running on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You can't without a Virtual Machine or Wine. Alternatively you could try Amarok and Banshee, which can also sync with your iDevice, and you can sort all music needs/etc with them. If you need to use the App Store you'll need to use the website [AppShopper](http://appshopper.com/).

Comment: Welcome to U&L.SE.  Nice concise answer

Answer (score 0):

If you really need iTunes I think the only option is to run it with wine

Comment: Do you have instructions to do that?

Comment: Ok aparently you cant, my bad full story here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/166903/how-do-i-install-itunes . Is there a reason you need itunes or can you try an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to spin up a Windows VM either with VirtualBox or VMWare workstation.  However, you would need to have a legit Windows license key for this.